# Meaning of eigenvalues of an adjacency matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I know the eigen vector of a matrix transformation is the vector that turns it into a scalar transformation.

But in the context of a adjacency matrix and in a graph, what does the eigen vector or eigen value mean?

Comment: The eigenvalues of matrices associated with graphs are related to graph connectivity, many other graph properties and have algorithmic applications. The branch of graph theory which studies that is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_graph_theory

Comment: Perhaps see also https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/109963/intuition-behind-eigenvalues-of-an-adjacency-matrix

Comment: And https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24978/spectral-graph-theory-interpretability-of-eigenvalues-and-vectors

Comment: If the matrix is stochastic (columns add to 1), and the Markov chain system converges, then the eigenvectors represent potential final states that are "fighting for supremacy" to become the "true" final state. The one that will win out to be the true final state is the eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue 1. (The others will have eigenvalues with magnitude less than 1.) There are analogous situations even without a stochastic matrix.